# Vue JS - How to get user id when clicking on a checkbox and then clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have users with their own checkboxes, I need to do so that when you select a specific user by clicking on the checkbox, then when you click on the "Get user id" button, get the user ID in the getUserId method.

Here is the [code in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-thunder-7bp8z)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="user" v-for="(user, i) in items" :key="i">
      <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.age }}</p>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <button @click="getUserId()">Get user id</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    getUserId() {},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Alex",
          age: 23,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Robert",
          age: 33,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Jacob",
          age: 55,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want to collect the *checked* user IDs. To do so, you should bind your checkbox *models* to an array and set the `value` to the `user.id`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    getUserId() {
      console.log("userIds", this.userIds)
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{"id":1,"name":"Alex","age":23},{"id":2,"name":"Robert","age":33},{"id":3,"name":"Jacob","age":55}],
      userIds: [] // start with an empty array
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <!-- Note: the `user.id` makes for a much better `key` -->
  <div class="user" v-for="user in items" :key="user.id">
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.age }}</p>
    <!-- Set the checkbox value to `user.id` and bind the model to your array -->
    <input type="checkbox" :value="user.id" v-model="userIds" />
  </div>
  <button @click="getUserId()">Get user id</button>
</div>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox